# Python - Parse requests response

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-requests

I've an endpoint where I post the data.

```
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

I get the following response in Javascript:-

```
throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
(function() {
    var r = window.dwr._[0];
    //#DWR-INSERT
    //#DWR-REPLY
    r.handleCallback("1", "0", {
        msg: "",
        output: {
            msg: "Showing from city center",
            resultcode: 1,
            scrpresent: true,
            srclatitude: "28.63244546123956",
            srclongitude: "77.21981048583984",
        },
        result: "success"
    });
})();
```

How do I parse the response? I basically want the `output` json. HOw can I get the same?

Comment: regex and json.loads

Answer (score 1):

The problem is - `output` is not a valid JSON string and cannot be loaded via `json.loads()`.

I would use regular expressions to locate the `output` object and then use `findall()` to locate key-value pairs. Sample working code:

```
import re


data = """
throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
(function() {
    var r = window.dwr._[0];
    //#DWR-INSERT
    //#DWR-REPLY
    r.handleCallback("1", "0", {
        msg: "",
        output: {
            msg: "Showing from city center",
            resultcode: 1,
            scrpresent: true,
            srclatitude: "28.63244546123956",
            srclongitude: "77.21981048583984",
        },
        result: "success"
    });
})();
"""
output_str = re.search(r"output: (\{.*?\}),\n", data, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE).group(1)

d = dict(re.findall(r'(\w+): "?(.*?)"?,', output_str))
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'msg': 'Showing from city center', 'resultcode': '1', 'srclongitude': '77.21981048583984', 'srclatitude': '28.63244546123956', 'scrpresent': 'true'}
```